# Get The Content In Data-Prefilltext attribute

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP and I have a HTML code like this

```
<button style="display:none" id="btnGGPShare0"  class="g-interactivepost" data-contenturl="http://www.tindich.com/18-bi-mat-vuot-thoi-gian-cua-nhung-nguoi-hanh-phuc/" data-clientid="208559429132-h4egkr4jjlagnk8r5jskic4d27oa4n4l.apps.googleusercontent.com" data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" data-prefilltext="Chúng ta thường nghe nói rằng sự nổi tiếng chỉ đem lại bất hạnh. Điều này không hề đúng! Vì cùng với một nhóm các nhà khoa học nghiên cứu về hạnh phúc, những người nổi tiếng của mọi thời đại đã cho biết họ có thể  chỉ ra được những bí mật để trở [&hellip;]" data-calltoactionurl="http://www.tindich.com/18-bi-mat-vuot-thoi-gian-cua-nhung-nguoi-hanh-phuc/" data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
```

Then I want to get all the content between double quotes of **data-prefilltext** attribute. 
Please suggest me some solutions for this. Thank you so much.

Comment: FYI added working php code to the answer. Let us know if it works for you. :)

Comment: Too bad that I can't vote +1 for you guys XD

Comment: Looks like you've got upvoting privileges now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all the disclaimers about parsing html with regex, this simple regex will do it (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kP9yO8)):

```
data-prefilltext="\K[^"]*
```

With php, you can do something like this (see results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/L9L2hG)):

```
$regex='~data-prefilltext="\K[^"]*~';

$string = '<button style="display:none" id="btnGGPShare0"  class="g-interactivepost" data-contenturl="http://www.tindich.com/18-bi-mat-vuot-thoi-gian-cua-nhung-nguoi-hanh-phuc/" data-clientid="208559429132-h4egkr4jjlagnk8r5jskic4d27oa4n4l.apps.googleusercontent.com" data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" data-prefilltext="Chúng ta thường nghe nói rằng sự nổi tiếng chỉ đem lại bất hạnh. Điều này không hề đúng! Vì cùng với một nhóm các nhà khoa học nghiên cứu về hạnh phúc, những người nổi tiếng của mọi thời đại đã cho biết họ có thể  chỉ ra được những bí mật để trở [&hellip;]" data-calltoactionurl="http://www.tindich.com/18-bi-mat-vuot-thoi-gian-cua-nhung-nguoi-hanh-phuc/" data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create>';

if(preg_match($regex,$string,$m)) echo $m[0];
```

**How does it work?**

- Match the character string “data-prefilltext="” literally (case insensitive) `data-prefilltext="`
- Keep the text matched so far out of the overall regex match `\K`
- Match any character that is NOT a “"” `[^"]*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`

Answer (score 2):

I would take advantage of parsing this using [`DOM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and avoid using a regular expression.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);  // Load your html data

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$node  = $xpath->query("//button[@id='btnGGPShare0']");

echo $node->item(0)->getAttribute('data-prefilltext');
```

See [**Working Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ujnq88)

If you have mutliple `button` tags that you want to extract that attribute from, use a loop instead.

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//button');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   echo $node->getAttribute('data-prefilltext') . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I got problem with the utf-8 display. I've added header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); but it wasn't work.

Comment: @omgpwned Use `$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));` and alternative, `$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged it to `regex`. A regex expression that would extract the mentioned text is:

```
(?<=data-prefilltext=")((?!").)*(?="\s)
```

I have no experience in PHP though.